# When is sizeof(int) not 4 bytes in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos, networking

I'm using an open-source networking framework that makes it easy for developers to communicate over a service found using Bonjour in Objective-C.

There are a few lines that have had me on edge for a while now, even though they never seem to have caused any problems on any machines I've tested, regardless of whether I'm running the 32-bit of 64-bit version of my application:

```
int packetLength = [rawPacketData length];
[outgoingBuffer appendBytes:&packetLength length:sizeof(int)];
[outgoingBuffer appendData:rawPacketData];
[self writeToStream];
```

Note that the first piece of information sent is the length of the data packet, which is pretty standard, and then the data itself is sent. What scares me is *the length of the length*. Will one machine ever assume an int is 4 bytes, while the other machine believes an int to be 8 bytes?

If the two sizes could be different on different machines, what would cause this? Is it dependent on my compiler, or the end-user's machine architecture? And finally, if it is a problem, how can I take an 8-byte int and scrunch it down to 4-bytes to ensure backwards compatibility? (Since I'll never need more than 4 bytes to represent the size of the data packet.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't assume that `sizeof(int)` will always be four bytes.  If the size matters, you should either hard-code a size of 4 (and write code to serialize values into four-byte arrays with the proper endianness), or use types like `int32_t` defined in `<stdint.h>`.

(However, as a practical matter, most compiler vendors have decided that `int` should stay four bytes, so you *probably* don't need to worry about everything breaking tomorrow. Then again, it wasn't so long ago that many compiler vendors let an `int` be two bytes, leading to many problems when `ints` became four bytes, so you really ought to do things the right way so guard against future changes.)

Comment: Kristopher, will there ever be a penalty to simply casting any larger types (or, just int) to int32_t? Is it safe to assume that the high order bits are truncated? I never expect any packet sizes to be larger than the max size of int32_t, so if the number is in fact larger than int32_t, it's an error elsewhere anyway.

Comment: The smart/safe thing to do would be to test the number before casting it to a smaller type.  You may not expect values to ever be too big, but if a hacker could exploit this (by sending a too-big packet, or sending a misformed packet), then you need to check.

Answer (score 3):

It could be different, but this depends on the compiler more than the machine. A different compiler might redeclare int to be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Size of int depends on machine architecture; size of int will be the size of the data bus almost always, unless your C compiler does something special and changes it.

That means size of int is not 4 bytes when you compile your program in a 8-bit, 16-bit or 64-bit machine/architecture.

I would define a constant for the buffer size instead of using size of int.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. When I compile/run my app as 32-bit or 64-bit, the sizeof(int) is 4 in both cases.

Comment: The C standard only dictates that sizeof(int) is at least 2. It is supposed to be the most "natural" size for an integer on the machine architecture, but compiler implementors choose whatever size they want.

Comment: @craig Because your current machine is a 32-bit machine, the Apple A4 processor,right?

Comment: @craig It would be good to know what you get if that same compiled program is executed in a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @craig All of which are running on 32-bit mode. Specifically Core 2 Duo and Core i7 may still be running on 32-bit mode unless you did or have done all of this:

Comment: @craig All of which are running on 32-bit mode. Specifically Core 2 Duo and Core i7 may still be running on 32-bit mode unless you did or have done all of this http://www.intel.com/technology/intel64/index.htm or this http://www.intel.com/products/processor/corei7/specifications.htm to enable 64-bit operation. And if you did or have done that and still you get 4 for size of int then I accept the Objective-C compiler is aligning integers to 32-bit regardless of data bus size, unless there's a switch to force it to use the machine size of 64-bit.

Comment: @Julio: The default for x86_64 using Apple's developer tools is to have 32 bit ints, 64 bit longs and 64 bit pointers.  It's a convention known as LP64.