# Unexpected looping in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, unsigned

I have this code:

```
unsigned int k=(len - sizeof(MSG_INFO));
NSLog(@"%d",k);
for( unsigned int ix = 0; ix < k; ix++)
{
    m_pOutPacket->m_buffer[ix] = (char)(pbuf[ix + sizeof(MSG_INFO)]);
}
```

The problem is, when:

```
len = 0 and sizeof(MSG_INFO)=68;
k=-68;
```

This condition gets into the for loop and is continuing for infinite times.

Comment: `unsigned int k`, k isn't -68, it's unsigned, it may well print off like that if you pass it to a function that doesn't know the difference, but really k is a large number... I'd expect your buffer to overrun, trashing memory as the loop runs / your application to crash.  This: `NSLog(@"%d",k);`  Should probably be: `NSLog(@"%u",k);`  so you know k's real value btw...

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @forsvarir You should post that as an answer because it's the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your code says: `unsigned int k`.  So k isn't -68, it's `unsigned`.  This makes k a very big number, based around [a 4 byte int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220683/when-is-sizeofint-not-4-bytes-in-objective-c), it would be 4294967210.  This is obviously quite a lot more than 0, so it's going to take your `for` loop a while to get that high, although it would terminate eventually.

The reason you think that it's -86, is that when you print it out with a function like `NSLog`, it has no direct knowledge about the arguments passed in, it determines how to treat the arguments, based around the format string, supplied as the first argument.

You're calling:
This:

```
NSLog(@"%d",k);
```

This tells `NSLog` to treat the argument as a `signed int (%d)`.  You should be doing this:

```
NSLog(@"%u",k);
```

So that NSLog treats the argument as the type that it is: `unsigned (%u)`.  [See the NSLog documentation.](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog)

As it stands, I'd expect your buffer to overrun, trashing memory as the loop runs and your application to crash.

After reflecting, I believe @FreeAsInBeer is correct and you don't want to iterate through the for loop in this situation and you could probably fix this by using signed ints.  However, It seems to me like you would be better off, checking `len > sizeof(MSG_INFO)` and if this isn't the case handling it differently.  Most situations I can think of, I wouldn't want to perform any processing after the for loop, if I'd failed to read sufficient information for a message...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is going on here, as the loop should never execute. I've loaded up your code, and it seems that the `unsigned` part of your `int` declaration is causing the issues. If you remove both of your `unsigned` specifiers, your code will execute as it should, without ever entering the loop.

Comment: The loop executes because k is a large number, you're comparing it to 0, the op is incorrect about k being -68, because they are passing the wrong format to NSLOG.  As an aside, how do you know not going into the loop is their desired outcome in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure k is a large number? The OP has stated that k is a negative, and if you run the code yourself using `-68` the loop still runs, even though it seems that it should not.

Comment: When you pass an unsigned number to a printf type function that is expecting a signed number (%d is usually a signed int format), it will treat the value stored in memory as if it is signed, and print out a negative number if that is appropriate. When you compare two unsigned numbers, the compiler isn't going to make that mistake, it will do an unsigned comparison. The declaration for both variables is in the ops code snippet.

Comment: If you remove 'the loop should never execute' from your answer, I'll remove my -1.  `ix` in the loop is declared as unsigned, so if you put `ix < -68` in the for loop, I'd expect a warning.  There's also a good chance the compiler would do an unsigned comparison, in which case it would convert the bit value of -68, to it's unsigned equivalent.  Negative numbers are usually represented by the high bit of the value being set, hence `(unsigned)-68` is a large number...  I don't know the number of bits in an int for objective-c, or I'd tell you how large :)